# Ansible connecting to host which is stored in a variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to connect to an host which is nothing but an cisco ios switch which I get by executing an powershell script. So basically the switch is output from an xml string from an powershell script. I am able to successfully receive the switch name from Ansible output. Now my question is how do I connect to the switch and see the details of the switch using show commands.

This my playbook:

```
hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Parse the XML output
      xml:
        xmlstring: "{{ hostvars[groups['win'][0]]['splat']['stdout'] }}"
        xpath: "/HostDiscovery/Host/Connection/NetworkDevice[Candidate='true' and  Uplink='false']/DeviceName"
        content: text
      register: data
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.DeviceName }}"
      with_items: "{{ data.matches }}"
```

This will give an output as follows

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/splat_executeps_script.yml:21
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'DeviceName': u'abc'}) => {
    "msg": "abc"
}

where abc is the host to which I need to connect to in the subsequent task in the same playbook.
I have tried writing something as below in the same yaml file:
hosts: "{{ item.DeviceName }}"

```
 connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: Show VLAN
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show vlan brief | include {{id}}
          - show interfaces {{interface}} status
      register: vlan
    - debug: var=vlan.stdout_lines
      with_items: "{{ data.matches }}"
```

But this does not run and gives the below error:

META: ran handlers
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/splat_executeps_script.yml': line 27, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- hosts: "{{ item.DeviceName }}"
  ^ here

How can I correct the details, any help would be appreciated? 
Please note that the device which I am trying to connect in the subsequent task would be dynamically generated by the xml which is returned from PS script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write : hosts: "{{ data.matches.DeviceName }}".
you must have in the same playbook two hosts:

```
hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Parse the XML output
      xml:
        xmlstring: "{{ hostvars[groups['win'][0]]['splat']['stdout'] }}"
        xpath: "/HostDiscovery/Host/Connection/NetworkDevice[Candidate='true' and  Uplink='false']/DeviceName"
        content: text
      register: data
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.DeviceName }}"
      with_items: "{{ data.matches }}"

hosts: "{{ data.matches.DeviceName }}"
connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: Show VLAN
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show vlan brief | include {{id}}
          - show interfaces {{interface}} status
      register: vlan
    - debug: var=vlan.stdout_lines
      with_items: "{{ data.matches }}"
```

Comment: ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'data' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/splat_executeps_script.yml': line 28, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: "{{ data.matches.DeviceName }}"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue using the below code:

- hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['data']['matches'][0]['DeviceName'] }}"